# win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents doesn't catch events and raises exception

Tags: python, com, win32com

I have to connect to COM interface (specific implementation), call some methods, get responses in both synchronous and asynchronous way. I had to mask some specific interface/methods names while pasting code samples. If I use **Dispatch** method only, everything **works fine**:

```
#works fine in synchronous mode
myObj = win32com.client.Dispatch(myObjID)
myObj.MyMethod1(0)
myResp = myObj.myMethod2()
print "property1: " + myResp.property1 #works fine
```

Problem starts when I need to get some events (**DispatchWithEvents**). It causes Python to crash ! Low level networking exception is thrown: **exceptions.EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**. Code sample which results in crash:

```
#crashing code
class SomeEvents(object):
    def OnMethod1(self):
        print 'OnMethod1'

myObj = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents(myObjID,SomeEvents)
myObj.MyMethod1(0) # CRASH OCCURS HERE!
```

I have checked what kind of object is actually returned by Dispatch and DispatchWithEvents:

Object returned by **Dispatch**:

```
<win32com.gen_py.myComInterface 1.0 Type Library.myComManager instance at 0x20508304>
['CLSID', 'MyMethod1', 'MyMethod2', 'MyMethod3', 'MyMethod4', 'MyMethod5', '_ApplyTypes_', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__getattr__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_', '_oleobj_', '_prop_map_get_', '_prop_map_put_', 'coclass_clsid']
```

Object returned by **DispatchWithEvents**:

```
<win32com.client.COMEventClass instance at 0x20462352>
['__del__', '__doc__', '__getattr__', '__init__', '__module__', '__setattr__', '_obj_']
```

In both cases there are objects of different types returned. Object returned by **DispatchWithEvents** is **COMEventClass** and it doesn't contain MyMethod1, MyMethod2 etc. (is that a reason of crash? I would expect "Object has no attribute" exception)

I also tried to implement it by creating 2 different objects. As a result, there is no crash but also no events are caught. Code sample:

```
#doesn't crash but also doesn't catch any events
class SomeEvents(object):
    def OnMethod1(self):
        print 'OnMethod1'

myObj1 = win32com.client.Dispatch(myObjID)
myObj2 = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents(myObjID,SomeEvents)
myObj1.MyMethod1(0) 
myResp = myObj1.MyMethod2()
print "property1: " + str(myResp.property1) #property displayed correctly
#no 'OnMethod1' printout visible
```

I was implementing COM client using examples found on internet. Python version: 2.7.6 (32 bit) on WinXP SP3. I couldn't search for any similar problem (what surprised me a little bit). What am I doing wrong? Perhaps specific implementation of COM has bugs? I think that next step would be to implement COM client using VB and check if it has similar problems. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to Excel via `DispatchWithEvents` and trigger some events (look at the excel interop docs online) and see if your listener gets them. If that works then something is wrong with your COM object, or you may have to generate the type library. You can do that by first using your object with `EnsureDispatch`, you only need to do this once ever. After that, see if using  `DispatchWithEvents` your Python obj still missing `MyMethod1` etc. If not, and the Excel (or any other production-quality COM server like Word or IE) COM instance events work, then there must be something wrong with your COM object.

Comment: Thanks for hints. I tried them but my script still fails. I succeeded in receiving events from Internet Explorer COM object. I also suspect that there might be something wrong with COM object.

Comment: I agree, that's the only reasonable conclusion at this point. I presume you have read the MSDN pages about [COM API and events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694379(v=vs.85).aspx)?